# Password reset flow Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, mobile, azure-ad-b2c

In Azure ADB2C pwd reset policy, once the user provides email and enters verification code can change email or update password. How to disable the option to change email and only give the ability to change password. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The only way is to use [CSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview#custom-html-and-css) to hide the element.

Navigate to `Page layouts`, and then under `Forgot password page`, click **Yes** for `Use custom page content`. You could refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-customize-ui) about customize UI.

Add code in the xxx.css([sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-AD-B2C-page-templates/blob/master/ocean_blue/css/common.css)) of reset password.

```
#email_ver_but_edit {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is the injected "api body" from Azure will override any changes to reveal that edit button. You need to listen for change events to override it.